# How do I use data I receive from API in JSON format?

Tags: c#, json, api, windows-phone-8

After I called an API (get) I received this answer:

```
"medios": [
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Banco Galicia",
        "type": "a",
        "img": "/method/21030342",
        "medios_id": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Bango River",
        "type": "Banco",
        "img": "/method/210321012",
        "medios_id": "0"
    }
]
```

And I have my "get / set" class:

```
public class Medio
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string img { get; set; }
        public string medios_id { get; set; }
    }
```

My question is: how do I make them work together... meaning: have id with the ids I receive from the api, and so on?

Thanks!

Comment: look in to Json.Net for example to deserialize your response..

Comment: Your JSON is missing an outer pair of braces: `{ "medios": [ ... ] }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the NewtonSoft.Json package from NuGet to convert the json to your class type list

```
List<Medio> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Medio>>(your_string)
```

Comment: Since it was a larger JSON, I had to deserialize a partial fragment as stated in http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try as follow:-

```
var yourObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Medio>>(json);
```